# Tso Host SSL confing Perch Cms

Tags: ssl, perch

I Have a Perch Runway website on TSO Host and having issues with setting up the https:// redirect

most of the ones i have tried result in redirecting to a error page

this is my current htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Perch Runway
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/perch
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule .* /perch/core/runway/start.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

but this works on all pages apart from the home pagewhere i get sent to 
/core/runway/start.php

Answer (score 0):

I use a different https redirect, which could be worth a try:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  # Perch Runway
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/perch
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule .* /perch/core/runway/start.php [L]
</IfModule>
```